# csapp: virtual memory is an abstraction for both the main memory and disk I/O devices

Tags: linux, file, memory, io, operating-system

I'm reading the book Computer System: A Programmer's Perspective(2nd).

In chapter 1.7(Fig 1.11), it says:

> virtual memory is an abstraction for both the main memory and disk I/O devices

Why is virtual memory an abstraction for disk I/O devices? I know virtual memroy is an abstraction of the main memory. And I know files are abstraction of disk I/O devices.

Comment: Because the page table entry could consist swap entry, which points to the place where page in stored in swap space (on disk)

Comment: How about ordinary disk files?@AlexHoppus

Comment: What do you mean?@Yuan Wen

Comment: I mean, is virtual memory also an abstraction of ordinary disk files?

Comment: What are you asking is totally depend on what are you put in definition of  "abstraction". One can say that, if you mmap file you get its data in virtual address space of your application, so you could access file data through virtual addresses. In this way you can think that VM is abstraction for files. I think you should assert on how exactly it works, rather than if it could be called "abstraction" or not.